# Apply a different stylesheet depending on the operating system you are using

Tags: html, css, macos, operating-system, frontend

My website has parts to it whose design are very sensitive with how they look down to the pixel.

http://sandhals.ca/

As it is, it seems to me that the little pop-ups from hovering appear okay on the above link if you are on MacOS. However, they don't seem to work on Windows. Instead if I adjust the pixels to how they are here:

http://sandhals.ca/index2/index

They seem to work. The question is though, how can I write something into either my HTML or my CSS to adjust the numbers depending on the operating system? Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: The error I get is: `Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rafaelp/css_browser_selector/master/css_browser_selector.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` Host the `.js` yourself

Answer (score 1):

You will need Javascript.
Add this to the bottom of your template or after the document has loaded. 
You can than style your document based on the classes on body.

```
<script> 
    var OSName="Unknown OS"; 
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows"; 
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS"; 
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX"; 
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux"; 

    document.body.classList.add( OSName);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! How should I utilize the effects of this Javascript in my CSS?

For example if I have a ```<div class="box"></div>``` and I want ```.box{margin-top:10px;}``` on Windows and ```.box{margin-top:12px;}``` on Mac, what would an implementation of that look like?

Comment: .Windows .box{margin-top:10px;}
.MacOS .box{margin-top:12px;}

it is just plain simple css from there.
usually the used OS shouldn't affect the appearance of your website anyway. chrome as an example should behave exactly the same on every OS

Comment: I've tried this, but don't seem to be getting it to work. Is using something like ```.Windows .box:hover ~ .box2{...}``` not going to work? I've placed the script inside of the ```<head>``` of my html.